# Oracle: how to run a stored procedure "later"

Tags: oracle, plsql

We have a system that allows users interfacing data into the database to set up various rules that are used to alter data before it is merged in to the main table. For example, an order might have a rule that sets up what delivery company to use based on a customer's address.

This is originally intended to operate only on the data being loaded in, so it's limited to functions that you can call from a select statement. An important point to note is that the data is not in the destination table yet.

Now, I have a project that requires an update to another table (fine - I can use an autonomous_transaction pragma for that). However, there are some functions I need to run that require the data to be inserted before they run (i.e. they are aggregating data).

So, I really want to just queue up running my procedure till some time later (it's not time dependent).

How do I do that in Oracle? The wealth of documentation is rather overwhelming when I just want to do something simple.

Comment: "autonomous_transaction pragma"  should be used sparingly - mostly in 'must audit no matter what' kind of situations.  Why are you not keeping it one transaction - "update to another table".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name => 'daily_tasks_job',
    job_type              => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action            => 'prc_daily_tasks',
  repeat_interval       => 'FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=1',
  enabled               => TRUE,
  comments              => 'Calls stored procedure once a day'
  );
END;

BEGIN
     DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name        => 'SHELL_JOB',
    repeat_interval  => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=2',
    job_type         => 'EXECUTABLE',
    job_action       => '/u01/app/oracle/admin/tools/shell_job.sh',
    enabled          => TRUE,
    comments         => 'Perform stuff'
);
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard aproach for this would be to use dbms_jobs to schedule a job calling the procedure.

If there is some precondition, the job could check the precondition. If it is fulfilled, the job continues, if not it reschedules itself and exit.

Comment: In Oracle 10 and 11 you can use dbms_scheduler or dbms_job, in Oracle 9 you can use only dbms_job.